# Replace carousel with static image

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I have a webpage with a carousel but I prefer not to load it when rendered in a mobile device.
How can I skip the initialization on mobile devices?

I came up with something like that (not optimized yet):

```
    jQuery(function($){  
  if($(window).width() > 767){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      directionNav: false,            
      controlNav: false 
    });
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 767){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        directionNav: false,            
        controlNav: false 
      });
    }
  });
 });
```

But I feel there should be a better way to do it. Any ideas?

On the CSS side I simply hide all the slides but the first one so I have only 1 image visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The site [detectmobilebrowsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)   has some javascript code to detect a mobile browser - you could just put an if round this and only instantiate the carousel if it is not a mobile browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only issue I see is that using the js code provided at detectmobilebrowsers I will not detect small viewports in desktops and the carousel will run with just 1 slide since the others are not displayed due to css.